# Filter JSON object list based on property value with property value is in another JSON object list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried the following code:

````
var Mylist={[text:"rate"], 
     [text:"domain"]};

     var newlist= 
     {[displayname:"rate"], 
     [displayname:"forms"], 
     [displayname:"domain"]};
     
     Mylist.forEach(element=> {
     newlist =newlist.filter(p => 
     p.displayname===element.text);
});
```
Whatever is contained in `mylist` should be filtered in `newlist`.

Note: both list are dynamic and keeps changing its property value.
````

Comment: To ensure we understand correctly, as items are added to either `MyList` or `newList` the `newList` should be filtered? Are items added then to the already filtered `newList` list? Or should they be filtered into a third, filtered list?

Comment: Suppose mylist contains rate,domains,choices then if newlist contains rate,forms,rules,domains then newlist should be filtered as newlist with rate,domains note:both list are changing oninit i have wrote here sample

Comment: Using reactive programming and Observables might do what you need. I'll work up an example for you (assuming someone doesn't close this question first).

Comment: I'm so sorry DeborahK.I'm typing on my phone and it's 5am here and i can't sleep with that question in my head

Comment: Can you add the expected outcome of your inputs?

Comment: let yFilter=this.mylist.map(itemy=>{ return itemy.text; });

this.newlist=this.newlist.filter(itemx=>yFilter.includes(item.Displayname));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let yFilter=this.mylist.map(itemy=>{ return itemy.text; });

this.newlist=this.newlist.filter(itemx=>yFilter.includes(item.Displayname));

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified example that uses two arrays as you've specified and uses an Observable as a notification mechanism. Whenever either array is modified, the Observable emits a change notification and refilters the list.

The basic code is this:

```
  mylist = [{ text: 'rate' }, { text: 'domain' }];
  newlist = [
             { displayname: 'rate' },
             { displayname: 'forms' },
             { displayname: 'domain' }
            ];

  // Define an Observable to post notifications
  private changeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  change$ = this.changeSubject.asObservable();

  filteredList$ = this.change$.pipe(
    map(() =>
      this.newlist.filter(item =>
        this.mylist.some(key => key.text === item.displayname)
      )
    )
  );

  addKey(key: string) {
    this.mylist.push({ text: key });
    // Change notification
    this.changeSubject.next(true);
  }

  addDisplay(name: string) {
    this.newlist.push({ displayname: name });
    // Change notification
    this.changeSubject.next(true);
  }
```

The UI is then bound to the `filteredList$` observable, so it automatically updates whenever the filtered data changes.

A working sample application can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-lists-as-data-changes-deborahk

If that isn't quite what you need, feel free to fork the stackblitz and update as required.